# Prevent observers on unloadAll

Tags: ember.js

I've written a little mixin that filters table records.

```
loadRecords: function() {
  var fc=this.get('content').toArray();
  fc = this._applyTextFilter(fc);
  fc = this._applyDropdownFilter(fc);
  if (fc.get('length') > this.get('viewLimit')) {
    fc = fc.splice(0, this.get('viewLimit'));
  }
  this.set('filteredRecords', fc.sortBy(this.get('sortProperties')));
}.observes('textFilter', 'selectedFilter', 'content.@each'),
```

Every now and then, however, I need to unload all the records.

```
this.get('store').unloadAll('entry');
```

This has the unfortunate side effect of running loadRecords every time a single record is removed. Even with a small record set this is very time consuming. I've also tried putting the unloadAll in a run loop, and change the `content.@each` to `content.[]` but neither attempt has helped.

How do I defer the calling of `loadRecords` until after all records are gone from the store?